# Running one thing after another in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, synchronous

I have this code snippet from something i am developing

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#Submit").click(function(){
        var Count = document.frmOne.count.value
        for (i=1;i<=Count;i++)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:"process.php",
                type:"get",
                data:$("form").serialize(),
                success:function(response){
                    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( response );
                    var success = obj.success;
                    var actionsNumber = obj.number;
                    $("#result").html('There have been  '+actionsNumber+'  loops completed');    


                }
            })
        }
                $.ajax({
                     url:"done.php",
                     type:"get",
                      })
        })
    })
</script>
```

and basically I need to have the whole for loop complete then have it run "done.php". But currently it seems to run done.php after about 2 loops in the for loop.

So lets see if i can explain this better. I have this whole js script run after someone clicks a submit button.  I have it run process.php for a user inputted amount of times, then i want it to run done.php after it finishes the for loop.  But it is currently running process.php about twice, then done.php, then continues with process.php.

How can i fix this?

Now i have tried this and it is not working still, any help please

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#Submit").click(function(){
        var Count = document.frmOne.count.value
        var b = 0
        for (i=1;i<=Count;i++)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:"process.php",
                type:"get",
                data:$("form").serialize(),
                success:function(response){
                    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( response );
                    var success = obj.success;
                    var actionsNumber = obj.number;
                    $("#result").html('There have been  '+actionsNumber+'  loops completed');   
                    b++;


                }

            })
    if(Count == b)
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url:"done.php",
                    type:"get",

                      })
                      var b = 0
            }
        }



        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: whats the value of Count that you are using?

Comment: and why are you sending the same data to "process.php" page count no of times?

Comment: count is just a number someone enters into a field,  and that was the only way i could get a live counter working for the number of times the loop has run

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - you need to set the option `async: false` in the ajax requests inside your for loop.

Longer answer - Your success function which prints out the number of loops only executes when the requests make it back to you, *not* when they're sent.  Your loop actually finishes before the request to `done.php` is sent, but you can't control the order that your requests come back in.  You can verify this by moving this line:
`$("#result").html('There have been  '+actionsNumber+'  loops completed');`
to right before the ajax request in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Keep another count, increase that count in the first ajax call's success callback (inside the loop). Then call the second ajax call to done.php only when that count reaches Count.

$.ajax is asynchronous and so in your code it won't wait for all the calls inside the loop to finish before going to the done.php call. That's how AJAX works.

Comment: Would you mind giving me an example.  I have a feeling that i would just add one to a var inside the loop  then put done.php request inside something like `if loopnumber = count{blah blah}` but i dont exactly know how to do that.  Sorry, i am new to ajax and js

Comment: can you check  what i added in my first post and help me figure out why it isnt working

Comment: sorry about the confusion. you should call the second ajax call to done.php in the success callback. At where you put the b++:

Comment: well when i put it there it seems to do nothing, as in it never calls done.php

Answer (score 0):

In your the looped ajax request success callback add the logic to check if it's the last ajax request callback if yes. Call the `done.php` call.

```
for(var i;i<=Count;i++)    
    $.ajax({
    ...
    ,success:function(data){
       if(Count == i)
       {
          $.ajax({
          ..
          url:"done.php",
          ..
          });
       }

    },
    ..
    });
}
```

Comment: well, if i do it how you posted then it freezes my browser then just keeps running the  for loop and doesnt stop, and if i put the ` if(Count == i)` outside the first ajax thing but still inside the loop it does the same thing, but i have an idea that i will try tommorrow